# how can i use getsource() with event from [org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event]

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, verify

i wanna verify input in Text.make sure the value is between 0 and 100. but because of some reason i can't use `VerifyEvent` to do it. as follows, i want to get "check" value in public void `handleEvent(Event event)` how can i do it

```
control.addListener (SWT.Verify, new Listener () {
    public void handleEvent(VerifyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Text text = (Text)e.getSource();
        String t = text.getText();
        String check = t.substring(0, e.start) + e.text + t.substring(e.end);
        e.doit = validateInput(check);
    }
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you want to add a `SWT.Verify`, but you cannot use a `VerifyListener` with `VerifyEvent` and consequently, cannot access `event.getSource()`. However, since you add the `Listener` manually, you know the source:

```
final Text textField = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
textField.addListener(SWT.Verify, new Listener() {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event e) {
        // You can access textField, since it is final
        final String oldS = textField.getText();
        String newS = oldS.substring(0, e.start) + e.text + oldS.substring(e.end);

        boolean isValid = true;

        if("".equals(newS))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                // first check, if text really is a number
                float value = Float.parseFloat(newS);

                // then check if it's between 0 and 100
                if(value < 0 || 100 < value)
                    isValid = false;
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException ex)
            {
                isValid = false;
            }
        }

        // if text is not a valid number, prevent user input
        if(!isValid)
            e.doit = false;
    }
});
```

So you add the `Listener` to `textField`. Hence, you don't need the `getSource()` method, because `textField` is the source...

Comment: sorry i didn't make this Q clear: in handleEvent(VerifyEvent e)   method： I already knew how to check value between 0 and 100,i wrote it in validateInput(check). the question is, i want use @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        // how to validate value here? Event seem has no getSource() method。How can i get string check as last method handleEvent(VerifyEvent e);
    }
VerifyEvent is clear to me, but Event i dont know how to get all input string. Unfortunately due to some reason,i can only use Event here..

Comment: @user1618488 Ok, changed my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: sorry for my late reply, it works!!! i changed textField to (Text)control to fit my project. but there is still a small bug: when i type 99 it's cool.if i want channge the value, i use backspace the 2nd 9 can be deleted.but the 1st 9 cannt. in a word: if i want change the value i input,i must choose all figures with the mouse and type a new value. i cant use backspace delete from the end to the front.anyway it works! i am thinking to add some foucus() method to kill the bug

Comment: seems that the input textfiled can not be null.so cannot delete the last figure

Comment: @user1618488 Added a check to my code. Now it will accept an empty text field. If it works for you, please consider accepting my answer.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help.i fixed the bug use newS.equals("")&&newS==null.anyway thanks again.

Comment: Just a sidenote: `newS.equals("") && newS==null` will never be `true`. `newS` cannot be `null` and therefore, the whole thing cannot be `true`. However, glad I could help.

Comment: forgive my noob.i mean || instead of &&.and now i know String cannot be null.